# How to retrieve data from angular model into a controller

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular6-json-schema-form

**drink-water.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from 'angular/core';
    import { userInfoService } from 'some/path';

    @Component({
    selector: 'drink-water';
    templateUrl: './drink-water.component.html'
    })

    export class DrinkWaterComponent implements OnInIt {
    ...
    ...
    userInfo: userInfoModel;

    constructor (public userInfoService : UserInfoService) {}

    ngOnInit() {

    this.readUsrInfo();

    }

    readUsrInfo() {
    console.log('user info is', this.userInfoService)

   //need gender here ..to do some logic
   //need gender here..

        }
```

**user-info.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserInfoModel } from 'some/path';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserInfoService {
public userInfo: UserInfoModel;

constructor() {}
}
```

**user-info.model.ts**

```
export class UserInfoModel {
gender: string;
userName: string;
hasKids: boolean;
constructor(data: UserInfoModel) {
this.userName = date.userName;
this.gender = data.gender;
}
}
```

**Console Output from drink-water component -> readUsrInfo( console.log())**
*Please replace > with downward solid arrow as a json structure. I could not format it*

```
   > userInfoService {}
    > userInfo : UserInfoModel
      userName: peggy
      gender: female
      hasKids: true
      student: false
      >foods: {vegetables: Array(3), Fruits: Array(5)}
    >_proto_: Object
```

**Question**

If I try to console just this.userInfoService from the controller, I get the above console output. How can I access the name and gender in readUsrInfo method? this.userInfoService.gender returns undefined.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you post the code of you UserInfoService?

Comment: @DPro Please see the updated code. I added the service and model code. Http request is done else where

Comment: try this.userInfoService.userInfo.gender. if you get error Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined it means your user info has not been initialized yet.

Comment: @DPro ...thanks for the reply...yup I am getting Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined. How can I initialize?

Comment: You said http request is done elsewhere, isn't it supposed to initialize it?

Comment: I see the data (pasted in the console output above)when I called the service in the controller and called in it in the method . But it is tied to the model and I can’t trickle down to gender.

Comment: I finally found the issue... the controller was initialized even before the http call was made. It is available in the console at a later point but not on init() of the controller. Thanks for all the support! #async

Answer (score 0):

```
export class UserInfoModel {
      userName= 'peggy'
      gender = 'female'
      ...
      ...
}

userInfo = new UserInfoModel()

console.log('user gender', userInfo.gender)
```